# progressbar no se muestra hasta que han finalizado los calculos

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un programa para repartir herencias, y tarda un poco en hacer los calculos. Por ello le meti un progressbar (circular). Pero la interfaz grafica (y por lo tanto el progressbar) no me carga hasta que no ha hecho los calculos con lo cual no sirve de nada. El progressbar se incrementa en el metodo `findCombinations` (que es recursiva) cada vez que se hace un calculo exitoso.
Este es el link al repositorio: [link al repo](https://github.com/palanganero/repartirHerenciasMinimo)

y este es el codigo del mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    ProgressBar pb;
    public ArrayList<Bien> A = new ArrayList();
    public  int k;
    public  int numerodecombinaciones=0;
    public static List<List<Bien>> combinaciones = new ArrayList();
    public long nCombTotales= 0;
    int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pb=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        Bien b1 = new Bien("revolta",1);
        Bien b2 = new Bien("bouzas",2);
        Bien b3 = new Bien("nazo",3);
        Bien b4 = new Bien("gradin",4);
        Bien b5 = new Bien("faro",5);
        Bien b6 = new Bien("niño de agre",6);
        Bien b7 = new Bien("gradin",7);
        Bien b8 = new Bien("faro",8);
        Bien b9 = new Bien("niño de agre",9);
        Bien b10 = new Bien("su outeiro",10);
        A.add(b1);A.add(b2);A.add(b3);A.add(b4);A.add(b5);
        //A.add(b6);//A.add(b7);A.add(b8);A.add(b9);A.add(b10);
        k =A.size();

        for(int l=1; l<=k;l++)
        {
            nCombTotales+=nCombinaciones(A.size(),l);
        }

        pb.setMax((int)nCombTotales);

        for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
        {
            findCombinations(A,i);
        }

        for(List<Bien> b:combinaciones)
        {
            for(Bien bien:b)
            {
                Log.i("hola",String.valueOf(bien.getNombre()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static long factorial(long numero)
    {
        long factorial=1;
        while ( numero!=0) {
            factorial=factorial*numero; numero--;
        }
        return factorial;
    }

    public static long nCombinaciones(long numero,long orden)
    {
        long nCombinaciones=factorial(numero)/(factorial(orden)*(factorial(numero-orden)));
        return nCombinaciones;
    }

    public void findCombinations(ArrayList<Bien> A, int i, int k,
                                 Set<List<Bien>> subarrays,
                                 List<Bien> out)


    {
        // entrada inválida
        if (A.size() == 0 || k > A.size()) {
            return;
        }

        // caso base: el tamaño de la combinación es `k`
        if (k == 0) {
            subarrays.add(new ArrayList<>(out));
            numerodecombinaciones++;
            pb.setProgress(numerodecombinaciones);
            return;
        }

        // comienza desde el siguiente índice hasta el último índice
        for (int j = i; j < A.size(); j++)
        {
            // agrega el elemento actual `A[j]` a la solución y repite para el siguiente índice
            // `j+1` con un elemento menos `k-1`
            out.add(A.get(j));
            findCombinations(A, j + 1, k - 1, subarrays, out);
            out.remove(out.size() - 1);        // retractarse

        }
    }

    public Set<List<Bien>> findCombinations(ArrayList<Bien> A, int k)
    {
        Set<List<Bien>> subarrays = new HashSet<>();
        findCombinations(A, 0, k, subarrays, new ArrayList<>());
        combinaciones.addAll(subarrays);
        return subarrays;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes de entender que existe el hilo de UI en el cual no deberías de hacer operaciones que causen bloqueos a la interfaz, para eso existen muchas alternativas para realizar procesos "pesados" en un hilo de trabajo ("por debajo")

Con eso puedes mostrar un ProgressBar mientras se ejecuta el proceso y actualizas el progeso cuando calcules algo.

AsyncTask es una opción (depreciada) con la cual puedes empezar para entender este concepto

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Otras opciones:

- Threads
- Executers
- RxJava
- Listenable Futures
- Coroutines (kKotlin)